# value an array with js based on the value of an element on the web page

Tags: javascript

I want to value an array with js based on the value of an element on the web page which is an array.
How can this be done?

```js
aa=JSON.stringify(document.querySelector("#a01").innerHTML)
console.log(aa[0])
```

```html
<div id="a01">[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]</div>
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` -> `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the element is already string. You should parse the *jsonString* using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to make that an array:

```js
var aa = JSON.parse(document.querySelector("#a01").innerHTML)
console.log(aa[0])
```

```html
<div id="a01">[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]</div>
```